# How would you put an Image next to a text cell for only parent rows in an outline view?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I am looking to have an image next to a text cell for only the parent rows in my Outline View.
Like what they have in Xcode: [alt text http://snapplr.com/snap/wsgp](http://snapplr.com/snap/wsgp)
. How would you do this or would you need a Custom Cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom cell for this. I've noticed you asking a few similar questions in the past, so if you haven't started down the road of custom cells yet this would be a good opportunity to do so. It's not too difficult to do, it will be helpful in understanding how cells work, and there are plenty of tutorials and sample code examples to go from. Here's one [example](http://www.martinkahr.com/2007/05/04/nscell-image-and-text-sample/), I'm sure you can find plenty of others through Google. There's even one in the Xcode sample projects, I believe under one of the NSOutlineView examples (or at least there was back around 10.3).

Comment: I think the example your talking about is called SourceView. I believe it has a custom cell class in it.